# At Flutter, how to insert into sqflite table but the table doesn't have an id with auto increment integer?

Tags: flutter, auto-increment, sqflite

I see that sqflite database helper instance insert function returns `Future<int>`. I understand if my table uses `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` as id. But what if my id is `STRING PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL`? What will be returned from the function, as the function insists to return `Future<int>`? How can I make the return value becomes `Future<String>`? Or can I just ignore this return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every SQLite table has an integer row id (https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) even if you use a text primary key. In this case you can ignore the return value.

Comment: Ah I see. I was having a concern about what it actually returns there, or whether it will cause crash or not in the future. Alright thanks!